# Free lightweight database program

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, database, portable

I need a smallish lightweight and **free** database program to keep track of items in a large collection. I don't need it to be able to do much besides being able to create entries with various fields that are searchable. I would like the program to be portable, but this is not a strict requirement. I don't need to be able to interact with the database using anything online.

I am thinking of something similar to a database program that could be used for a book collection at a library.

The program should be able to run on Windows 8, but if possible I would like one that works on Linux also.

Comment: Do you want something on a "consumer level" (with a GUI making it possible for non-techies to interact with it) – or just a "database engine" you interact with via SQL queries? In the former case, it would be helpful to have a few more details on your "items", e.g. what information (fields) must be available. Speaking of a "book collection", if that's really what it is for, there are many apps available – be it [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) with a nice and fancy GUI, or my own [miniCalOPe](https://github.com/IzzySoft/miniCalOPe) (web-based).

Comment: @Izzy: Yes, I am just looking for something on a non-tech level. Something that will just work right out of the box. I don't need it for books specifically.

Comment: Then it would make sense to [edit] your question and give a few more details – e.g. what "fields" you need, what "items" you want to manage (as I already pointed out in my first comment). The better you describe your needs, the better answers can be written to meet them.

Answer (score 6):

What I would do if you wanted something portable and lightweight is to use an application like **[Database Browser](http://www.etl-tools.com/database-browser/overview.html)** and have a connection to an SQLite database (an sqlite database is just a file acting like a database that can be copied to a usb for portability).

Database Browser Portable is an easy to use tool allows you to connect to any database and browse or modify data, run sql scripts, export and print data. It's packaged as a portable app so you can work on your databases on the go.

Features

- Works directly with Oracle, MS Sql Server, ODBC, MySql, PostgreSQL, **SQLite**, Ole DB, Interbase and Firebird
- Support for ODBC connection strings
- Unlimited number of connections
- One click switching from one connection to another
- One click table browsing
- Data browsing
- Data exports into CSV, Excel, Html files
- Execution history
- SQL Builder with wide range of supported databases
- Execution Log
- Incremental Table Search
- About 8MB installed
- Free

[image: Database Browser User Inderface]

You could also use **[DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)** which works on both Windows and Linux Operating Systems but is less lightweight compared to the Database Browser

DB Browser for SQLite is a high quality, visual, open source tool to create, design, and edit database files compatible with SQLite.

It is for users and developers wanting to create databases, search, and edit data. It uses a familiar spreadsheet-like interface, and you don't need to learn complicated SQL commands.

Controls and wizards are available for users to:

- Create and compact database files
- Create, define, modify and delete tables
- Create, define and delete indexes
- Browse, edit, add and delete records
- Search records
- Import and export records as text
- Import and export tables from/to CSV files
- Import and export databases from/to SQL dump files
- Issue SQL queries and inspect the results
- Examine a log of all SQL commands issued by the application

[image: SQLite User Interface]